# Import Excel Range into Access ISAM error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So I've been trying to put together this last piece of this VBA script and the connection to the database is giving me problems. The database opens but right after I get and error `could not find installable isam` I tried to register the DLL, no luck, I tried different versions in the connection, no luck.

At this point I am at a loss. All this is trying to do is import a range in an Excel sheet to the Access database. If anyone has a reason why it is giving me this error, please help.

```
Sub Open_Database()
Dim appAccess As Object
Dim pathToDatabase As String
    pathToDatabase = Environ("USERPROFILE") + "\Desktop\FuturesDemandScheduling - Copy.mdb"
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase pathToDatabase, True, "password"
    Windows("FuturesFIle-2014.xlsx").Activate
    appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3, _
    "futuresData", _
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
    False, _
    "A2:G491"


    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
    appAccess.Quit
Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which versions of Excel and Access are you using?

Comment: 2010, it is a `mdb` file we are trying to connect to.

Comment: Does this make a valid path? I'd think that `Environ("USERPROFILE") + "\Desktop\FuturesDemandScheduling - Copy.mdb"` makes something like `Brandon_Wilson\Desktop\FuturesDemandScheduling - Copy.mdb` which cannot be found.

Comment: As stated, the database opens but it will give me that error. That is a valid path to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the way you are importing the excel data into the table

Since you said the version of `excel is 2010` and you are using `.xlsx` file extension in the code

Try

`acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` instead of `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3`

**acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3** supports **Excel 3.0** Format

**acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml** supports **Excel 2010**

[Complete list here](http://ss64.com/access/acspreadsheettype.html)